# Problems while running C# application on a mac using mono

Tags: c#, winforms, macos, mono

I have a C# WinForms application with very simple controls: Message boxes, labels, pictureboxes and textboxes. I want to be able to run this app on a Mac so I downloaded mono and ran it using the terminal.

I have 2 questions:

1.) How do I make the default process for a windows based exe application to open using the framework so I dont have to open it from the terminal every time?

2.) The controls don't appear at the right position. Most of the labels, textboxes have moved their position and the position of a button on the screen is not where it is supposed to be clicked but a little below it. The form looks perfect on Windows.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How have you laid out your controls? You might have more luck of you instead lay them out via docking/anchoring properties than by just letting them float within a container. Mac -> Windows you'll have all sorts of DPI and resolution issues which will play with the layout - best to use the Docking and Anchoring properties and try again.